# Shiny conditionalPanel shows all conditions on all tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I am a newbie in Shiny and I  have this code. I have created 3 tabPanels. When I run the Shiny App - it is showing all the set of condition in all of the tabs. Depending on the tab that I selected, it should only display the items in the condition that have met. I have change the different names of the item  just like other people suggested but it still seems doesn't worked on my end.

Any help is relay much appreciated.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected=='AAA'",
        selectInput("selectDisease1", 
                   label="Select Disease:", 
                   choices=c("Disease 1","Disease 2") 
                   ),

        selectInput("selectProduct1", 
                   label="Select Products:", 
                   choices=product.list, 
                   selected=NULL, 
                   multiple=TRUE
                   ),

        selectInput("selectStartDate1", 
                   label="Select Start Date:", 
                   choices=names(SBI[c(5:num.columns)]), 
                   selected = 1
                   ), 

        selectInput("selectEndDate1", 
                   label="Select End Date:", 
                   names(SBI[c(5:num.columns)]), 
                   selected = 1
                   ),

        submitButton("Submit")

      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabs=='Data'",
        selectInput("selectDisease2", 
                    label="Select Disease:", 
                    choices=c("Disease 1","Disease 2")  
        ),

        selectInput("selectProduct2", 
                    label="Select Products:", 
                    choices=product.list, 
                    selected=NULL, 
                    multiple=TRUE
        ),

        selectInput("selectStartDate2", 
                    label="Select Start Date:", 
                    choices=names(SBI[c(5:num.columns)]), 
                    selected = 1
        ), 

        selectInput("selectEndDate2", 
                    label="Select End Date:", 
                    names(SBI[c(5:num.columns)]), 
                    selected = 1
        ),

        numericInput("lines2", 
                     label="Number of Lines:", 
                     value=1
        ),

        dateRangeInput('dateRange2',
                       label = paste('Date range input 1:'),
                       separator = " - ", 
                       format = "yyyy-mm",
                       startview = 'month'
        ),

        submitButton("Submit")

      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabs=='Plot'",
        selectInput("selectDisease3", 
                    label="Select Disease Stage:", 
                    choices=c("Disease Stage 1","Disease Stage 2")  
                    ),

        selectInput("selectProduct3", 
                    label="Select Products:", 
                    choices=product.list, 
                    selected=NULL, 
                    multiple=TRUE
                    ),

        selectInput("selectStartDate3", 
                    label="Select Start Date:", 
                    choices=names(SBI[c(5:num.columns)]), 
                    selected = 1
                    ), 

        selectInput("selectEndDate3", 
                    label="Select End Date:", 
                    names(SBI[c(5:num.columns)]), 
                    selected = 1
                    ),

        numericInput("trends3", 
                     label="Number of Linear Trends:", 
                     value=1
                    ),

        dateRangeInput('dateRange3',
                       label = paste('Date range input 1:'),
                       separator = " - ", 
                       format = "yyyy-mm",
                       startview = 'month'
                      ),
       dateRangeInput('dateRange4',
                       label = paste('Date range input 2:'),
                       separator = " - ", 
                       format = "yyyy-mm",
                       startview = 'month'
                      ),

        submitButton("Submit")

      )      
    ), 

    mainPanel(
      titlePanel("Assessment"),

      tabsetPanel(

        id = "tabselected",
        selected = NULL, 

        tabPanel("AAA Disease State", 
                 value="AAA", 
                 tags$hr(),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("sbirx.view", width = 300)
                 ),
        tabPanel("Data",
                 value="Data",
                 tags$hr(),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("sbirx.view", width = 300)
                ),
        tabPanel("Plot",
                 value="Plot",
                 tags$hr(),
                 DT::dataTableOutput("sbirx.view", width = 300)
                 )

      )

    ) # end of main panel

  ) # end of sidebarLayout

) # end of fluidpage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your rendering of the datatables, outputs should be unique. You can render `sbirx.view` only once, if you want to display the output 3 times then assign something like `sbirx.view2` and `sbirx.view3` and then render it. Also remove the `submitButton` and assign `actionButton` to each one as @GGamba suggested

```
tabsetPanel(

id = "tabselected",

tabPanel("AAA Disease State", 
         value=10, 
         tags$hr()
         #,DT::dataTableOutput("sbirx.view", width = 300)
),
tabPanel("Data",
         value=20,
         tags$hr()
        #,DT::dataTableOutput("sbirx.view", width = 300)
),
tabPanel("Plot",
         value=30,
         tags$hr()
         #,DT::dataTableOutput("sbirx.view", width = 300)
)
```

)

Comment: @aotearoa Please accept the answer if this was the solution

Comment: Yes, I accept the answer as this is the resolution to my problem.  Thank you for your time in looking into this. Have a great day!

Comment: @aotearoa Please click on the green box beside the voting window. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem (maybe it's intended) where `conditionalPanel` does not work if there is a `submitButton()` inside the panel.

To fix it use an `actionButton()`.

Note that you will have to change you server code appropriately.

Comment: Appreciate your response GGamba. However I tried using the actionButton(). It still the same problem. I tried running without any SubmitButton() or actionButton(). It is still the same problem.